# How to get youtube audio data through given url

Tags: javascript, html, audio, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Currently I'm working on a audio data analyzing project.

I want to let user to key in a Youtube URL

and get the URL's youtube audio data back to my website.

After getting the data I want to store them in a 1-D array for further signal processing.

Can this task be finished only via Javascript?

thanks in advance.

btw, the audio data is like :(for example:wav audio format)
[0.5,0.9,0.26,0.44,0.23,0.01,0.11,0.54,......]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

> II. Prohibitions
>   ...
>
> 8. separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any
>      YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;
> 9. promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube
>      audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

So you can't separate the audio from video.

Comment: thanks for reply.
but is there any alternative way to accomplish that?
like......load both vedio & audio data using API
but only keep the audio one by some javascript